# Retrieving all google tags xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Im parsing a xml file but im having some issues regarding a tag (":g"), i cant access the information, his content, the problem is when i try to get the categories, i have more than one category.

xml:

```
<item>
      <g:id>4011700742288</g:id>
      <title><![CDATA[4711 Acqua Colonia Blood Orange & Basil Eau de Cologne 170ml]]></title>
      <link><![CDATA[https://url/asdasd.html]]></link>
      <g:image_link><![CDATA[https://url/media/catalog/product/4/7/4711-acqua-colonia-blood-_2.jpg]]></g:image_link>
      <g:price>34.86 EUR</g:price>
      <g:product_type><![CDATA[Mulher]]></g:product_type>
      <g:product_type><![CDATA[Homem]]></g:product_type>
      <g:product_type><![CDATA[Unisexo]]></g:product_type>
    </item>
```

I try getting the categories using for example:

```
$categories = $item->children('g', TRUE)->product_type;
```

But it only brings the first category, is not geting the rest of the categories.
Here above is my code example of how i get the data.
ex:

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
         $categories = $item->children('g', TRUE)->product_type; 


        // bringing in to array <content:encoded> items from SimpleXMLElement Object()
        $content = xmlObjToArr($item->children('content', true)->encoded);
          echo $categories . PHP_EOL;
    return;
}


function xmlObjToArr($obj) {
        $namespace = $obj->getDocNamespaces(true);
        $namespace[NULL] = NULL;

        $children = array();
        $attributes = array();
        $name = strtolower((string)$obj->getName());

        $text = trim((string)$obj);
        if( strlen($text) <= 0 ) {
            $text = NULL;
        }

        // get info for all namespaces
        if(is_object($obj)) {
            foreach( $namespace as $ns=>$nsUrl ) {
                // atributes
                $objAttributes = $obj->attributes($ns, true);
                foreach( $objAttributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue ) {
                    $attribName = strtolower(trim((string)$attributeName));
                    $attribVal = trim((string)$attributeValue);
                    if (!empty($ns)) {
                        $attribName = $ns . ':' . $attribName;
                    }
                    $attributes[$attribName] = $attribVal;
                }

                // children
                $objChildren = $obj->children($ns, true);
                foreach( $objChildren as $childName=>$child ) {
                    $childName = strtolower((string)$childName);
                    if( !empty($ns) ) {
                        $childName = $ns.':'.$childName;
                    }
                    $children[$childName][] = xmlObjToArr($child);
                }
            }
        }

        return array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'text'=>$text,
            'attributes'=>$attributes,
            'children'=>$children
        );
    }
```

Comment: Since you're not actually using the result of the `xmlObjToArr` function in the code you show, you can [edit] and remove that from your example. My advice would be to remove it from your code as well, and just use SimpleXML objects as they are intended to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

```
$categories = $item->children('g', TRUE)->product_type;
```

This will set `$categories` to an object which gives you access to all the `<g:product_type>` elements.

Your problem is when you write:

```
echo $categories . PHP_EOL;
```

This displays *the text content of a single XML element*. Since `$categories` is a collection of multiple elements, SimpleXML guesses that you want the first one. In other words, it's equivalent to:

```
echo (string)$categories[0] . PHP_EOL;
```

Where `(string)` extracts the text content and is implied by `echo`, and `[0]` gets the first item in the collection.

Looping over the collection of elements works exactly how you'd expect a list to work - you use `foreach`:

```
foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
    echo $cat . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and clarification